# Power Series Proof w/ Binomial Coef.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Prove that, for any positive integer k,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {{n+k \choose k}z^n}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}},  |z| < 1$$

Answer (score 2):

We have for $\vert z \vert < 1$,
$$\dfrac1{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$$
Differentiate both sides $k$ times to conclude what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$f(z)=(1-z)^{-(k+1)}$$

differentiate a few times, and see what you get for $f^{(n)}(0)$. As an example

$$f'(z)=(k+1)(1-z)^{-(k+2)}\implies f'(0)=(k+1)$$

Then $$f''(z)=(k+1)(k+2)(1-z)^{-(k+3)}\implies f''(0)=(k+1)(k+2)$$

**SPOILER1** Prove by induction that

> $$f^{(n)}(0)=(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+n)=\frac{(n+k)!}{k!}$$

**SPOILER2** Using the above, what is

> $$\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\text{ ? }$$

Answer (score 0):

I think there is quite easy way to solve it. We will use identity:$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{p}{k}\cdot x^k=(1+x)^p$$ Right side of your identity is:$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{p+1}}=\left ( 1+(-x) \right )^{-(p+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-(p+1)}{k} \cdot (-x)^k=\sum\frac{(-p-1)\cdot (-p-2)\cdot \dots \cdot (-p-n)}{k!}\cdot (-x)^k=(-1)^k \sum \frac{(p+1)\cdot (p+2)\cdot \dots \cdot (p+n)}{k!}=\sum \binom {p+k}{k}\cdot x^k$$and it is easy to check that $\binom{p+n}{n}=\binom{p+n}{p}$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + k \choose k}z^{n} = {1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{k+1}}\,,
     \quad\verts{z} < 1:\ {\large ?}.\qquad\mbox{Lets}\ \fermi\pars{z,k} \equiv
     \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + k \choose k}z^{n}\,,\quad\fermi\pars{0,k} = 1}$.

> \begin{align}
> \fermi'\pars{z,k}&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + k \choose k}z^{n}=
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n + k}! \over k!\pars{n - 1}!}\,z^{n - 1}
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{n + 1 + k}! \over k!\,n!}\,z^{n}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{n + 1 + k}\,{\pars{n + k}! \over k!\,n!}\,z^{n}
> =\bracks{z\,\partiald{}{z} + k + 1}\fermi\pars{z,k}
> \end{align}

$$
\pars{1 - z}^{k + 1}\fermi'\pars{z,k}
- \pars{k + 1}\pars{1 - z}^{k}\,\fermi\pars{z,k} = 0\quad\imp\quad
\partiald{\bracks{\pars{1 - z}^{k + 1}\fermi\pars{z,k}}}{z} = 0
$$

> $$
> 0 = \pars{1 - z}^{k + 1}\fermi\pars{z,k} - \pars{1 - 0}^{k + 1}\fermi\pars{0,k}
> = \pars{1 - z}^{k + 1}\fermi\pars{z,k} - 1
> $$

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + k \choose k}z^{n} = {1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{k + 1}}}
$$