# Binomial series property for $|z| \lt 1$

Tags: probability, complex-analysis

I had a lecture where we proved the following identity: $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| \lt 1$.

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{\alpha}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {\alpha +k-1\choose k}z^k$$

Now i know this proof is already in a [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367448/power-series-proof-w-binomial-coef), but the proof that we had in class was different, namely the proof was the following:

**Proof**:

since $\frac{1}{1-z}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ we have:

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^n}=\sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty z^{i_1} \dot {} \dot{} \dot{} \sum_{i_n = 0}^\infty z^{i_n}$$

until here nothing too difficult, but now I did not understand the step that my professor did. He wrote on the blackboard:

$$\sum_{i_1 = 0}^\infty z^{i_1} \dot {} \dot{} \dot{} \sum_{i_n = 0}^\infty z^{i_n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k \dot{}\sum_{i_1+...+1_n=k}1$$

**Why is that true?** After that to conclude the proof he said that:

$$\sum_{i_1+...+1_n=k}1= {n+k-1 \choose k}$$

because this is exactly the number of nonnegative integers solution to the equation

$$i_1 +...+i_n=k$$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to read it like
$$
\sum_{i_1}z^{i_1}...\sum_{i_n}z^{i_n}=\sum_k(\sum_{i_1+...+i_n=k}1)z^k
$$
If you going to write out the LHS then you want the know the coefficient in front of $z^k$ you want to know how manny different ways  $z^{i_1}\cdot...\cdot z^{i_n}=z^{i_1+...+i_n}=z^k$ so how many ways $i_1+...+i_n=k$. Which is what we have on the RHS.

Addition: There is also a nice combinatorial prove that says 
$$
\sum_{i_1+...+i_n=k}1={n+k-1\choose k}={n+k-1\choose n-1}
$$
Say you have $n+k-1$ positions and $n-1$ division bars on each position you can place such a bar. the amount of empty positions between bar $a$ and $a+1$ equals $i_{a+1}$ then there are exactly $n+k-1\choose n-1$ ways to place you bars.